# How was this image achieved? With a filter?

Tags: instagram

Looking at Instagram I'm trying to get this one
If you don't know but thinks about anyone who knows please tell me where to look for the answer... Ty

https://instagram.com/p/-ZndnvTVLN/

Ty

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that JoJo Pearson has an idea which filter or processing was carried out on the image.  She can be contacted [here](https://instagram.com/p/-ZndnvTVLN/) or [here](https://www.instagram.com/lemonadejar/)

Comment: Variations on this question come up so often that we almost need a template response that says "this cannot be achieved with only a software filter but requires careful lighting and exposure considerations, blah blah".

Comment: I think there should be room for questions like "How was this achieved?"

Comment: When they verbalize *this effect* effectively enough to differentiate it from *that effect* these type of questions are generally well received. But this is probably the hundredth time someone has asked, "How did they do *this*?" without telling us, in words, what *this* is.

Comment: @Fred42vid There's plenty of room — these are some of the most interesting types of questions we have. But please see 
[Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions). Terry, it'd be helpful if you could read this, too, and add to the description and edit the title to be more specific.

Comment: @Fred42vid Your title edit helps a little bit, in that it removes the assumption that filters and post-processing are the key (see also, by the way, [What should we do with questions which assume photography is all Photoshop tricks?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/what-should-we-do-with-questions-which-assume-photography-is-all-photoshop-trick)), but it doesn't address the core assumption of what the "this one" Terry wants to get actually _is_.

Answer (score 5):

This specific look isn't the result of an Instagram filter.

How to create such an image?

- It's a high-key setup with light sources leaving barely a shadow: probably a soft box or beauty dish right behind the camera, as you can see in her eyes.
- The camera was set to overexpose a stop or two.
- She wears a special makeup: In one comment she states that it's called "cement". No need to mask red lips in Photoshop/Gimp and change the hue to a cement-like color.
- The image is quite desaturated, but it's hard to tell whether her makeup & outfit has these colors or whether it was desaturated with software.
- Finally, I believe the contrast was increased. This could have been done with an Instagram filter, but Photoshop/Gimp is better suited for that, because you have to observe the histogram to not clip the highlights.

In short, there is so much care of details which an off-the-shelf filter cannot achieve.

Answer (score -1):

It's the product of using a high end lightning device which leaves no shadow traces. It's not the product of an Instagram filter

Comment: What lighting device do you think was used? What makes you say "high end"?